# How do XMPP/HTML/etc. *really* work?

Tags: http, tcp, xmpp

This might be a dumb question, however, I have been continually frustrated by what seems to be a big gap in every explanation I've seen of protocols like XMPP or HTML. So basically, when I've read documentation on either, in general, it will describe the structure of the data sent back and forth through the protocol, but it does not explain exactly how this data is transferred. It's one thing to provide an example of, say, a generic HTTP request, but it is something else to explain how this text is actually sent to the server.

I guess posed another way, what resources are there out there for learning best practices for implementing text-based protocols? At their core, are all text-based protocols basically the exact same thing? How, for example, would it differ at the binary level, were I to say send the text content of an HTTP request over IRC vs however it is done natively by HTTP?

If I wanted to develop my own, simple textual protocol, what would be the best way to send the text to a client? Does the content itself even really matter? What I mean is that, obviously, HTTP and XMPP are rather different protocols, but do they differ in terms of how the text is transferred between computer to computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP, IRC and XMPP are all sent on top of [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), which is a protocol that provides a bidirectional stream between two endpoints (IP address + port).  Under the hood, the data you send is split into separate packets, sent across the network, and reassembled on the other end, so that the recipient just sees a stream of incoming data - except when something goes wrong; there is a somewhat accessible description [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

What that means is that while the application protocol (HTTP, XMPP etc) is different, the underlying transport mechanism is exactly the same.  It would be possible (perhaps even interesting) to implement HTTP on top of IRC: an HTTP/IRC client enters a channel, sends the HTTP request as messages to the channel, line by line, a server is present in the channel, reads the request and sends the response the same way - but transporting HTTP over IRC is fundamentally different from transporting HTTP over TCP.  The former means layering an application protocol over another application protocol (and the IRC connection needs to go over TCP anyway), while the latter is an application protocol over a transport protocol, which is the way things usually are done (except for various kinds of proxies).

Hope that makes some sense...